# Why does regexp_replace replaces nothing with something?

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I have to update several scripts to use a table from another schema:
**S1.MYTABLE** => **S2.MYTABLE2**.

Also when I replace the name of the table I want to keep the format of the original script. Keeping enter or space after **S2.MYTABLE2** if there was one after **S1.MYTABLE**

My code seems to work fine, but at the end of the string concats **S2.MYTABLE2**.

**This is my tests script**: (this is just simplified example of my problem)

```
DECLARE
   testtext VARCHAR2(2000) := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "S1"."MY_FUNCTION" (PARAMETER1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   something1    VARCHAR2 (50);
   OUTsomething   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE_RELATED
       WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE
       WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;

   SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE                                  
        WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;
END;';

   script CLOB;
   owner VARCHAR2(30) := 'S1';
   object_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'MYTABLE';
   output_name VARCHAR2(30) := 'MYTABLE2';
   destination VARCHAR2(30) := 'S2';

BEGIN

        script := regexp_replace(testtext, OWNER || '[[:space:]]*\.[[:space:]]*' || OBJECT_NAME || ' ', DESTINATION || '.' || OUTPUT_NAME || ' ',1, 0, 'i');
        script := regexp_replace(script, OWNER || '[[:space:]]*\.[[:space:]]*' || OBJECT_NAME || '\s|($)', DESTINATION || '.' || OUTPUT_NAME || CHR(13) || CHR(10),1, 0, 'i');                
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(script);                    
END;
```

The code of the function MY_FUNCTION, although unrealistic, exemplifies all the cases I am dealing with.

**Result of running this script:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "S1"."MY_FUNCTION" (PARAMETER1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   something1    VARCHAR2 (50);
   OUTsomething   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE_RELATED
       WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2
       WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2 WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;

   SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2                                  
        WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;
END;S2.MYTABLE2
```

As you can see **S1.MYTABLE** has been replaced by **S2.MYTABLE2** in all relevant places, maintaining the originally formatting (spaces and enters).

But for some reason **S2.MYTABLE2** is concatenated at the end.

**Why is regexp_replace concattenating S2.MYTABLE2 at the end of the script?**

**Is there a better way to achieve what I want?** Replace a table with another, keeping the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
\s|($)
```

That represents an alternating match that will end up replacing the end of string anchor with the new text. I think you want this instead:

```
(\s|$)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because of `|($)` in the second regex. Not sure why you wanted it there.

On removing that -

```
DECLARE
   testtext      VARCHAR2 (2000)
      := 'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "S1"."MY_FUNCTION" (PARAMETER1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   something1    VARCHAR2 (50);
   OUTsomething   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE_RELATED
       WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE
       WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;

   SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE                                  
        WHERE COLUMN2 = ''xx'' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;
END;';

   script        CLOB;
   owner         VARCHAR2 (30) := 'S1';
   object_name   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'MYTABLE';
   output_name   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'MYTABLE2';
   destination   VARCHAR2 (30) := 'S2';
BEGIN
   script      :=
      REGEXP_REPLACE (
         testtext,
         OWNER || '[[:space:]]*\.[[:space:]]*' || OBJECT_NAME || ' ',
         DESTINATION || '.' || OUTPUT_NAME || ' ',
         1,
         0,
         'i');
   script      :=
      REGEXP_REPLACE (
         script,
         OWNER || '[[:space:]]*\.[[:space:]]*' || OBJECT_NAME || '\s',
         DESTINATION || '.' || OUTPUT_NAME || CHR (13) || CHR (10),
         1,
         0,
         'i');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (script);
END;
```

Here is the output without the table name at the end -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "S1"."MY_FUNCTION" (PARAMETER1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   something1    VARCHAR2 (50);
   OUTsomething   VARCHAR2 (50);
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S1.MYTABLE_RELATED
       WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2
       WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;

       SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2 WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;

   SELECT COLUMN1
        INTO OUTsomething
        FROM S2.MYTABLE2                                  
        WHERE COLUMN2 = 'xx' AND COLUMN2 = PARAMETER1;                                           
   RETURN OUTsomething;
END;
```

EDIT: You may want to do what @DavidFaber's answer says in case your regex pattern may also appear at the end of the entire string (not just the end of a line).